# Different enums in child classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two almost similar classes to handle mouse and keyboard input in my cpp program. I would like to remove code duplication, unfortunately I can't figure out a way to "inherit" or redeclare `enum class` from base class in derived class. Let me show you an example:

```cpp
class DeviceHandler {
public:
  enum class Button; 
  bool getState(Button btn) { return buttonStateMap[btn]; } //same code for both classes
  virtual void onEvent(Button btn, SomeEventClass event) = 0;
};

class KeyboardHandler : public DeviceHandler {
public:
  enum class Button { shift, ctrl, alt, win, ... };
  typedef Button Key; //because Key make more sense for kb

  void onEvent(Key key, SomeEventClass e) override { /*do something*/ }
};

class MouseHandler : public DeviceHandler {
public:
  enum class Button { left, right, middle };

  void onEvent(Button btn, SomeEventClass e) override { /*do something*/ }
};
```

So, even though `enum class Button` has different meanings and implementations in both derived classes, button (key) state is the same thing everywhere. However cpp doesn't allow such behavior - that's why I can't move some identical code to other class. Is there a way except (probably) using C style enums without `class` or type features that cpp offers?

Comment: How do you call code with `DeviceHandler`?

Comment: Do you need two different classes for the mouse and keyboard? Or could one class to handle "buttons/keys" including the keyboard and mouse buttons, and one to handle "vector like" inputs such as the scroll wheel and mouse position work for what you need?

Comment: @Jarod42 MouseHandler ms; ms.getState(MouseHandler::Button::left)

Comment: @kjhayes,  I don't think it is possible to have one class handle different devices because it would make things too complicated.

Comment: But your example usage doesn't use DeviceHandler. The reason C++ doesn't let you do this is because there's no immediate way to use it. What *unified interface* do you want DeviceHandler to present? If there is none then just don't use inheritance. E.g. notice all the standard containers share a lot of interface (esp. iterators) but because they don't share type signatures they don't use inheritance to represent their similarities.

Comment: @HTNW, example shows reason I can't remove identical code from both classes. Code in DeviceHandler meant to be used as I show it to Jarod42. Maybe I'm doing smth wrong to achieve my goal, but at this moment I don't understand what exactly. So, am I using inheritance wrong?

Comment: Alright, then the answer is just templates. Don't have the time for a full answer but make DeviceHandler take Button as a template parameter and everything else should make sense (though you can't put the enum inside each class). Most of the time people want this they're not thinking about why they want it, so thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @HTNW, oh, right, I completely forget about them for some reason. Thanks!